# Counting diff makes the script exit if there is no diff

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I try to count some files in conflicts :

```
let initialConflicts=`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | wc -l`
```

The problem is : if there is no conflict, the result of `git diff` is empty and `wc -l` hangs. It seems to come from either a missing option in `git diff` or in `wc -l`. This small script reproduces the problem :

```
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

echo $SHELL
echo "Before counting"
let test=`echo -n "" | wc -l`
echo "After counting"
```

Here, the line "After counting" does not appear.

Comment: More minimally: `let test=0; echo $?` prints `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `let` in `bash`'s man page:

> Each arg is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated
> ...
> If the last arg evaluates to 0, let
> returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.

As you've `set -e`, this causes the script to exit. Since you're not evaluating an expression here, just:

```
test=`echo -n "" | wc -l`
```

should work.